# Simplifying following Boolean Expression and verify using Karnaugh Map

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, digital, digital-logic

I'm having trouble simplifying these two boolean expressions algebraically and proving them with a Karnaugh Map. How can I do this?

These are my two expressions:

> 1) (X * Y) + (X' * Y * Z')+ (Y * Z)
>
> 2) (X * Y') + Z + (X' + Y)+ (Y * Z)

I've tried going through it using the boolean theorems and laws to reduce them but I always come up with different answers. My answers usually comes up as this.

> 1) (Y * Z') + (X' * Y)
>
> 2) (X' * Y') + (X * Y' * Z')

I don't know if my K-Map is wrong, but I do need someone to help me understand how to solve this problem and the steps or laws I need to get the answer, so that I can master it. It is practice for exam, and I suck at boolean algebra. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first expression:

```
E = XY + X'YZ' + YZ
```

The three terms have `Y`, then we can factor it out

```
E = Y(X + X'Z' + Z)
```

Now let's concentrate in the expression in parenthesis `S = X + X'Z' + Z`:

```
S = X + X'Z' + Z
  = X + (X + Z)' + Z         (De Morgan)
  = (X + Z) + (X + Z)'       (regrouping)
```

so, despite the fact that this still looks complex it has the form

```
S = p + p'
```

for `p = X + Z`, right? But `p + p' = 1` (or `true`) no matter the value of `p`. Thus the expression `S` is `1` and we get

```
E = Y(X + X'Z' + Z) = YS = Y1 = Y
```

In other words, the first expression reduces to `Y`.

Notice also that it is not that hard to see why `S = 1` without rewriting it. There are three cases: (a) If `X` is `true`, then certainly the expression is `true`. (b) If `Z` is `true`, the result is `true` also. (c) If none of `X` and `Z` are `true` then both are `false` and `X'Z'` is `true`. So, in each of these 3 cases at least one of the terms is `true`, hence their sum.

Let's now consider the second expression

```
F = XY' + Z + (X' + Y) + YZ
```

The first thing to note is that `XY'` is the opposite of `(X' + Y)`:

```
(X' + Y) = (XY')'            (De Morgan)
```

So,

```
F = XY' + (XY')' + Z + YZ
```

Again, regardless of the fact that `XY' + (XY')'` looks complicated, it is an expression of the form `p + p'`. But `p + p' = 1` (it is always `true`) and therefore

```
F = 1 + Z + YZ = 1
```

no matter the values of `Y` and `Z`. So, the second expression is nothing but `1` (aka `true`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help!